# I want to fetch Product ID from Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I am retrieving Product Information from Firebase, but the issue is that I can't select any specific ID that is stored in Firebase.

I tried different solutions for the problem including `get(position)` but it's getting the position of the product in the RecyclerView

This the ProductsAdapter `onBindViewHolder` function.

Changes are added using *'s

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product productCurrent = mProducts.get(position);
        holder.product_title.setText(toCapitalize(productCurrent.getpTitle()));
        holder.product_pice.setText("$: " + productCurrent.getpPrice());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(productCurrent.getpImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.product_image);

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ProductPreview.class);
                intent.putExtra("pImageUrl", productCurrent.getpImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("pTitle", toCapitalize(productCurrent.getpTitle()));
                intent.putExtra("pPrice", productCurrent.getpPrice());
                intent.putExtra("pDescription", toCapitalize(productCurrent.getpDescription()));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

This Code is from the ProductsActivity having the `RecyclerView`

```
    private ProductsAdapter mAdapter;

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ArrayList<Product> mProducts;
    ***ArrayList<ProductKeys> mProductKeys;***

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.products_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        ***mProductKeys = new ArrayList<>();***

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");

        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Product product = postSnapShot.getValue(Product.class);
                    mProducts.add(product);
                    ***mProductKeys.add(postSnapShot.getKey());***
                }
                mAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(ProductsActivity.this, mProducts);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ProductsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Getting Error:

```
(com.*)
in ArrayList cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)
```

Please help me out of this... Thanks in Advance

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show anything about how you interact with Firebase. It'll be hard to help with seeing that.

Comment: Question update Sir... Please have a look

Comment: Educated guess: are you trying to determine the Firebase Database ID of the item at `position` in the `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get the ProductID of a specific Product to send it in ```Intent``` and update the Ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to determine the Firebase Database ID of the item at `position` in the `onBindViewHolder` method, you will have to maintain that mapping yourself. You can easily do this by extracting both the `getKey()` as well as the `getValue()` from the snapshot in `onDataChange` and keeping lists of both of them.

Something like this:

```
mProductKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Product product = postSnapShot.getValue(Product.class);
            mProducts.add(product);
            mProductKeys.add(postSnapShot.getKey());
        }
        mAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(ProductsActivity.this, mProducts);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

And then in the `onBindViewHolder` you can look up the key for the item that was clicked on in `mProductKeys`.

Comment: I have added this Line ```ArrayList<String> mProductKeys = new ArrayList<String>();``` and ```mProductKeys.add(postSnapShot.getKey());``` but how to access in ```AdapterClass onBindViewHolder```?

Comment: How about passing it into your adapter, similar to how you already pass in `mProducts`?

Comment: hi Frank! I tried this one also by creating a new class named ```ProductKeys``` but while passing the ```mProductKeys.add(postSnapShot.get());``` it shows error ```add cannot be applied to (java.lang.String).``` just Updated my Question... Please Have a look

Comment: Thank You @Frank, can't do it without your Clues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried different things and @Frank's answer gave me some idea to do this. Just added one Line and its done. :) No Need to add `ArrayList<String>`.

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Product product = postSnapShot.getValue(Product.class);
            product.setpKey(postSnapShot.getKey());
            mProducts.add(product);
        }
        mAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(ProductsActivity.this, mProducts);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

And Added the `String pKey` to my `Product.class` with `Setter and Getter`.